# Owl Carousel 2 nested autoplay loop

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel-2

Seems the nested carousel is working, but the inner carousel isn't triggering autoplay looping function properly which it stops after it changes to the second slide. I'm trying to make the inner carousel as autoplay looping fadeout carousel, but it just worked once, then need to refresh to restart the loop.

Don't know what's wrong with my code.

Here's my code.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dej98buf/1/)

```
$('.main-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:true,
items:1,
});

$('.fade').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:true,
items:1,
animateOut: 'fadeOut',
autoplay:true,
autoplayTimeout:1000,
autoplayHoverPause:false
});
```

Comment: It seems that you if you will remove the animation of your inner carousel it will work just fine, I think it has to do with the animation.

Comment: @JamesSolomonBelda but need the swap function in the inner page. its like a photo gallery, will just having a photo and dots as for the image indicator. could you assist for this matter sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slider').owlCarousel({  
        animateOut: 'zoomOut',  
        nav: true, // Show next and prev buttons    
        navText: false,    
        dots: true,  
        loop: true,  
        items: 1,  
        margin: 0,  
        smartSpeed: 450,  
        autoplay: true,  
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,  
        autoplayHoverPause: true  
    });
```

Comment: jquery, owl-carousel